# C++ VS2010 no linker in project->properties

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, linker

I have problem with .lib files not found. I would like to check linker properties. However, in Project->Properties, I cannot find linker tab. What am i missing here ? Actually, I fear that I am not looking at project properties, but at properties for solution or whatever. What is a project exactly (which icon in VS for instance), or where can I look at project properties ?

Thanks !!

Comment: Do you have added your *.lib file to Additional Library Directories (Project -> Linker -> General)?

Comment: Make sure when right-click the solution explorer item to bring up properties, it is the *Project*, not the *Solution* that is selected under the mouse. The solution properties are remarkably dull by comparison.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If there is no linker options, it is possible that the project is set to build a *.lib.

In this case you will be able to select 'Librarian' on the left of the project options. You can modify what the project is configured to build by going to General and then changing the Configuration type.

To get to the Project properties, right click on the project in the solution explorer window and click on properties.

Answer (score 0):

It should be Project -> Properties(Alt+F7) -> Configuration properties -> Linker. Dependencies can be set in the Input tab under the Linker tab.

Answer (score 0):

For clarification of the concept of "Projects" in Visual Studio:

The topmost node you see in the Solution Explorer (The panel which is (I believe) by default on the left of your window) is called the **Solution**. You can imagine it as a big bag to put everything related to solving a problem into.

This "everything" I'm talking about is put together using **Projects**. A project is essentially a bunch of code that is to be compiled into one distinct output file (a DLL/LIB, an application).

For instance, if you yourself were to write a library, you would create a solution encompassing all of it. Into the solution, you'd put the code of your library's components in separate projects. For testing, you'd add even more projects, each building an executable that is linking to your libraries.

For example:

```
---- MyLibrary (Solution)
     |
     +--- MyLibraryMath (Project)
     |
     +--- MyLibraryNetwork (Project)
     |
     +--- TestMath (Project, linking to MyLibraryMath)
     |
     +--- TestNetwork (Project, linking to MyLybraryNetwork)
```